# Good practice for loading many small audio files

Tags: javascript, html

What is a good way to handle the load of many small audio file (wav, mp3...)? I want to build a web based piano with 88 keys. Each key is associated a tiny wav file. I know it wouldn't be good to hit the server with 88 requests. I am thinking about bundling them (file concatenation or single audio file) and split them up in javascript. Is this a common practice and is there a javascript library for this?

Comment: Why not use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) to make the sounds and avoid downloading sound files altogether? There's a piano example on this page: https://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/samples.html

Comment: is synthesizing piano sound easy? I think that might be the best solution.

Comment: @neilsimp1 is right - it's relatively easy and would be a great way to reduce load times.

Comment: @neilsimp1, brod Web Audio API doesn't seem to support IE 11. sorry I should have mentioned cross browser compatibility.

Comment: you can zip them all into one file, and unpack the zip in JS.

Comment: Check out howler.js.
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/
The feature you're looking for is called 'sound spriting'. You can send down one big audio file from your server, and then define different sounds as pieces of the large audio file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some general comments:

I bet you have already decided that you really really need a separate file for each key, for reasons of realism?
Otherwise, you might consider e.g. just sampling the C key of every octave and altering the pitch, to decrease memory consumption. A lot of realism also comes with the dynamics, that means the velocity of the key strokes. For a realistic sound, there should be separate samples for different velocity ranges. With the sample-per-key-approach, you will eat a lot of RAM then.

If you stick to your original plan, maybe you could try to create one big WAV file where every key is played consecutively. Then you could find out the indices of each note (sample start/stop number/index) and play back just the respective range. With compressed formats, the feasibility of this approach would depend on the playback library you use.

Comment: does altering the pitch mean that I have to do a fourier transform on the client side?   I originally planned to go with one mp3 file but the files's duration are not uniform. Ill have to re-index if I change one of the files.

Comment: With "altering the pitch" I meant you can play the WAV data at different speeds. Pitch is the frequency of the piano strings, the faster you play a WAV file, the higher the pitch (frequency). Depending on the playback library you use, you need to keep resampling in mind. If you e.g. play the samples without any playback library, that is, feeding the wav data sample-per-sample into the sound output buffer (sink), you need to interpolate between samples, so audio quality is not degraded. There's a lot of literature on that.

Comment: Ah, I just need to resample. That's a nice approach. Ill give it a try. Thank you.